# Images are being squished in Microsoft Edge 16 - Small images in Edge

Tags: wordpress, browser, responsive-design, microsoft-edge, srcset

There is a bug in Microsoft Edge 16 (that has been reported several times and been confirmed here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7778808/ .

It squishes the image to a height of 30 pixels. Here is an example:

[image: Squished image from Microsoft Edge - Small image Edge]

Why does this occur and how do one fix it?

Comment: Hey, are you sure this is Microsoft EdgeHTML 16? We fixed this issue in 16 which began shipping on October 17th. Please let me know if you're still repro'ing this.

Comment: I can't reproduce it myself, - but I have 3 clients (with 3 different sites), - and they are all experiencing it. So I strongly assume that it's still a problem. :-/

Comment: My gut is that they aren't updated to 16 or it's in cache at that size we've reached out to numerous of the reporters on that thread to get repros and ensure the repro they had went away. If you can get a verified repro on EdgeHTML 16+ please don't hesitate to let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The fix**

If you're using Wordpress, then insert this in the bottom of your `functions.php`-file:

```
/*
 * Work-around for Microsoft Edge bug ( https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7778808/ )
 */
function custom_edge_browser_fix() {
  global $is_edge;
  if( $is_edge ){
    add_filter('wp_calculate_image_srcset', '__return_false');
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_edge_browser_fix' );
```

What this does it that it disables (removes) this `srcset`-tag in Microsoft Edge-browsers. This might have a slight effect on the loading-time for the page in Microsoft Edge, - but people using that browser doesn't have a soul anyway...

---

**The explanation**

I work for an agency, where we have had this reported from 3 individual sources within the past 2 days, - so I assume that it must be happening quite a lot.

The bug is (as far as I've heard) only in Microsoft Edge and are related to lower bandwidth connections. As can be read in the bug-report, then it appears that it isn't on every load, with a slower connection that the bug happens. So it is quite the corner case.

`srcset` is a tag that can be utilized to show different size images, based on the size of the view-port upon loading of a website. Wordpress automatically generates the different sized and automatically generates this tag as well and chucks it on images. If the tag is removed (as above-written code does in Microsoft Edge), then the original size image will be loaded every time, disregarding size of view-port.

If you're getting this error and you're not using WordPress, - then you can get around it by just removing the `srcset`-tag in another way... Or wait for Edge 17 to be released and rolled out. :-)

**Minor addition**

I had to clear the server-cache for the fix to take effect on some pages. One could also just wait a while (like a day or so) and let the cache expire by itself.

Comment: Glad you found the bit of code I mentioned on the Microsoft forum helpful. Is the `$is_edge` global your own or something that WordPress generates?

Comment: Yeah, thanks @SimonPollard !! You saved me hours with that, - and hopefully my post here can do something similar for others. 
The `$is_edge` is described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

Comment: I would recommend not doing this universally for all Edge UAs, I would only do it for Edge < 16

Comment: There's no such variable, 'our-of-the-box': https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

Comment: Won't this fix fail if the site uses page caching? I found a jQuery-based fix on the Microsoft issues page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7778808/ (posted Jun 16, 2017) that modified the src attribute with the addition of a random number. It won't fix the issue for non-javascript, but preserves srcset and works with caching.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error also happen on Chrome, has anyone else?  by far not as much as IE Edge,  but I have came across it on Chrome on my wordpress site.

Comment: It is rather comment, but not an answer !

Comment: Ihhh..  One more of these ones. @asch ... He hasn't got enough rep to comment. :-/

Comment: And Dave... Does it fix it (in Chrome), if you remove the srcset-tag (ref: my answer from above)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed in the Edge version released in the Creators Update Fall.

Comment: Helpful comment.  Not an answer.

Comment: Yeeh, - but he doesn't have enough reputation to comment. I feel bad for the poor fellow. :-/

Comment: Awww....  Rats.  And now I can't un-downvote him because it's locked.  :(

Answer (score 0):

What about the [Picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) polyfill?

Comment: That is not a suggestion to a solution. Or at least not elaborated enough for people to use it as a solution. Please consider to comment instead.